# META-INF/services/java.sql.Driver file

Tags: java, mysql, jboss

Could someone explain what the content of this file should be? it seams to be important for jboss 7.1.1. In my configuration now im not able to connect to the database.And i think this missing file could be the reason. Does anybody know the content of this file?

Comment: Maybe it just needs to hold the fully qualified driver class name.

Comment: just Maybe?? ;-) maybe the pat to?

Comment: It is a part of the MySQL Connector/J JDBC driver. It is there to satisfy the `ServiceLoader` interface requirements. Its content is really none of your business. If your problem is really an exception, as appears in comments, you should have posted it, instead of posing this classic XY problem.

Answer (score 1):

DriverManager uses this info to find available JDBC drivers. DriverManager API:

*JDBC 4.0 Drivers must include the file META-INF/services/java.sql.Driver. This file contains the name of the JDBC drivers implementation of java.sql.Driver.*

Comment: that means i have to write into that file mysql-connector-java-5.1.24-bin.jar

Comment: No, you have to write the name of the Driver class, `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`. But you really don't need this since the jar already has it.

Comment: com.jdbc.mysql.Driver??without any pre words or something..just this?

Comment: Or in other words: make sure you're using Java SE 6 or greater and a JDBC 4.0 compliant driver. (The driver jar should already include this file.)

Comment: im using this all...but if the driver jar got this file...do i need the meta.inf file?

Comment: @pulse All you need is to put mysql-connector.jar on the class path and DriverManager will automatically detected and use it

Comment: if the jar got it why does it throw an exception..specified driver not found

Comment: believe me...its in the class path...that is my problem